# Change default topic name of joint_state_broadcaster?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use moveit2 in ROS2. However in my application, I would like to change the default topic name of `/joint_states` (published by the `joint_state_broadcaster`) to a custom name without using relay, since another node in my setup is publishing to `/joint_states`.

Below is the `panda_ros_controllers.yaml file` that I am using. How would I change the published topic name for `joint_state_broadcaster` to something else?

```
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 100  # Hz

    panda_arm_controller:
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    panda_hand_controller:
      type: position_controllers/GripperActionController

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster


panda_arm_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity
    joints:
      - panda_joint1
      - panda_joint2
      - panda_joint3
      - panda_joint4
      - panda_joint5
      - panda_joint6
      - panda_joint7

panda_hand_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joint: panda_finger_joint1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394886/change-default-topic-name-of-joint_state_broadcaster?/) by [a.g](https://answers.ros.org/users/51535/a.g/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2022-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having more than one publisher on `/joint_states` is totally fine as long as there is only one source of information for a particular joint. It's very common for the `/joint_states` topic to have one message containing information about joints 1-3 followed by another message containing joints 4-6. So it shouldn't be necessary to do this, unless you have a case where you have more than one node publishing about the same joint (in which case that's a different problem) or you have more than one robot in your setup and so there needs to be some differentiation by topic (in which case you should be using namespacing).

Either way, the easiest way to get namespacing going here will be in your launch files. You can also remap topics in the same file. Take a look at the wiki [here for ROS1](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) or [here for ROS 2](http://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Launch/Creating-Launch-Files.html?highlight=remap).

---

Originally posted by [cst0](https://answers.ros.org/users/92869/cst0/) with karma: 119 on 2022-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-01-24**:
Please note: the OP tagged this `ros2`. You link to the ROS 1 wiki.

**Comment by [cst0](https://answers.ros.org/users/92869/cst0/) on 2022-01-24**:
Thanks for the catch, I've updated with an additional link.

**Comment by [a.g](https://answers.ros.org/users/51535/a.g/) on 2022-01-24**:
Thank you this helped a lot!